# Where to position Back and Home buttons?

Tags: icons, mobile-application, position

When you watch tv on a tablet via an app, where do you put the "Back" icon and where do you put the "Home" button?

Comment: Just a personal opinion - but for me 'back always takes me to the left - so the 'back' icon should be on the left hand side.

Comment: Wouldn't that depend on the mobile OS you're using? In general, different OSs have different conventions. For example on android I'd expect either a physical back button or an OS supplied back button, not a back button that's part of the application UI.

Answer (score 2):

**They should not move around and blend into the device itself.**

> "it’s the content that is most important to the user — the part of the UI they need to focus on most. The chrome, when it’s working well, should seem invisible and natural."
>
> *source: [Jared Spool](http://www.uie.com/brainsparks/2009/01/27/uietips-previous_next_luke/)*

Both content and chrome are important but I would say the best experience will come from following the standards on each device so the buttons blend in and aren't different from other back buttons on the same device.  I'll link to the big two below.

---

#### [Interface Guidelines for Android Devices](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html)

- back button is bottom left
- home button is bottom middle

[image: android]

#### [Interface Guidelines for Apple Devices](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/)

- back button is top left
- home button is usually a tab on the bottom (or link in the top right)

[image: apple]